# Cross product of vector functions of different (input) dimensions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

If I take the cross product of a vector function $\mathbf r(t)$ and a vector field $\mathbf A(x,y,z,t)$, is the result itself a vector field?

What is in general true if we take the cross product of vector functions/vector fields with different dimensions? What is the dimension of the cross product?

I.e. the cross product of ($n\neq p$)
$$
\mathbf B:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^3 
\text{ and }\mathbf C:\mathbb R^p\rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $$
Or the cross product of ($n=p$)
$$
\mathbf D:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^3 
\text{ and }\mathbf E:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf C$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the cross product $\mathbf B\times \mathbf C$ is a vector that depends from  the two vector field and is a vector field $\mathbf B\times \mathbf C:\mathbb{R}^n \times\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ .

The case of $\mathbf D$ and $\mathbf E$ is a special case.

Comment: Thanks! Is $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^p=\mathbb R^{n+p}$? This is called the the cartesian product, right?

Comment: Yes, it is the  cartesian product and it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n+p}$